# create a new field based on other vector layers attributes (pyqgis)

Tags: python, attributes, qgis

I'd like to create a new field in vector layer "Join", based on attributes in vector layers "Buildings" and "Intersection" but PyQgis returns a series of worng numbers, particularly just the first feature value of the field "Intersection" (I suppose the error is in the for cycle's script/sequence). Could you help me?

```
featuresB=layerBuildings.getFeatures() 
featuresJ=layerJoin.getFeatures() 
featuresI=layerIntersection.getFeatures()    
for fJ in featuresJ:
    for fI in featuresI:
         for fB in featuresB:
             if fI.geometry().area()*2>=fB.geometry().area():
                print fI[field_x]
             else:
                print fJ[field_y]
```

Comment: where you call provider.changeAttributeValues ,for example?and this triple for is not correct.Do you have a complet example?Which is the field of union between shapefiles?

Answer (score 1):

I attach a small example following the idea you want to make.
But if you do it without any union field you will overwrite values.

I hope to be of help or as a guide to solve your problem

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

#TOC Layers
layerB = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('farmacias')[0]
layerJ = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('call2016')[0]
layerI = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('albergues')[0]

#Provider
provider = layerJ.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes( [ QgsField('new_field', QVariant.String)])
layerJ.updateFields()

#Loop           
for j in layerJ.getFeatures():
    #print "Layer Join :" + str(j)
    for b in layerB.getFeatures():
        #print "Layer Buildings :" + str(b)
        for i in layerI.getFeatures():
            #print "Layer Intersection :" + str(i)
            #if "your condition"
            provider.changeAttributeValues({j.id() : {provider.fieldNameMap()['new_field'] : i[0]}})
            layerJ.updateFeature(j)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help and sorry for the delay. First of all, I'm not sure to have understood your comments. 
(a) do you consider the error is (just) in the order of for statement? i.e. for joined layer, then for building layer, then for intersection?
(b) Plus, i have to add the povider.changeAttributeValues in place of "print etc" . 
do you confirm that?

Comment: you need make union of attributes in some place!what is val= fI[1]. The order is not important in this case,sorry for change it.Print is for show value in console but not chage or add value in attributes layer

Comment: Answering you: (1) of course I had first joined the layers in the conventional way (running a script, for instance); (2) "val" is just a name for the values that, you're right, I have to add to the attribute table by means of provider.changeAttributeValues. Anyway tank you

Answer (score 1):

2nd, you asked for the whole code: here it is with small changes:

```
joined_layer=QgsVectorLayer(path,name,"ogr") 
intersected_layer=QgsVectorLayer(path,name,"ogr") 

featuresJ=joined_layer.getFeatures() 
featuresI=intersected_layer.getFeatures() 
featuresB=Bld_layer.getFeatures() 

for fJ in featuresJ: 
   for fI in featuresI: 
     geomI=fI.geometry() #lo piglia 
     for fB in featuresB: geomB=fB.geometry() 
       if geomI.area()*2>=geomB.area():
          val= fI[1] 
       else: 
          val= fJ[2] 
       print val
```